# Block CSS Transition on addClass

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have the following code which works great for hover transitions:

```
#main_nav a, #main_nav a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    color: #808080;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

#main_nav a:hover, #main_nav a:active, #main_nav a.active {
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

However, when I use JavaScript to apply the class `active` I would like it to immediately take the properties without firing the transition. I've been digging and can't find anything on this...

Here's a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7WsrY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent it from happening you need to override the css transition applied by 
`#main_nav a` by placing a new rule as below, so that the transition is reset if class `active` is applied, otherwise the anchor will inherit the transtion from the rule `#main_nav a`:

```
#main_nav a.active {
    transition:none;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JFGzg/)

Comment: Note that you'll still get a transition if you remove the class with JS.